# Transferring Image between two scenes in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have an image in main view controller and i want this image to be shown in new view controller...I know how to get string values between two scenes but no idea about images in storyboards....please help me out...

```
Is it right way to pass UIImage to another controller...

if UIImage *img1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]; and UIImageView is *newimgview  for newViewController

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"imageview"])
    {
        newViewController *nvc=segue.destinationViewController;
        nvc.newimgview.image=img1;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ...finally I got it...using this code

```
In case  UIImage *imag1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"some.png"];

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"imageview"])
    {
        newViewController *nvc=segue.destinationViewController;
        nvc.imag2=imag1; //imag2 is UIImage that globally declared in newViewController
    }
}

And in newViewController under ViewDidLoad or wherever u want to use...

self.imageview2.image=imag2;
```

Thanks for all ...

Answer (score 1):

just pass the `UIImage` pointer the same way you are doing for other data like `NSString` in `performseguewithidentifier`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image, you can just call it in your ViewController, no need to pass it.

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

or

```
[UIImage imageNamed:filename]
```

If you don't initially have the image you can pass it's pointer along like you would a string. Read up here for more info: [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the file path to the destination view controller or you could really pass the image if you want so. Add this method and try passing the image

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourImageTransferSegue"]) {

            YourImageTransferViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            destViewController.imageObject = self.imageToBeTransfered;

    }
}
```

In **YourImageTransferViewController's** ViewDidLoad or wherever you want use the image object as **self.imageObject**